# NodeSchool IO Exercies 3

Tags: node.js

I've started learning node.js

I'm currently on exercise 3, where we have to, based on a file buffer, calculate the number of new line characters "\n"

I pass the tester but somehow if I create my own file file.txt, I am able to get the buffer, and print out the string, but it is unable to calculate the number of new lines (console.log(newLineNum)) returns 0

Here is the code

```
//import file system module 
var fs = require("fs");

//get the buffer object based on argv[2]
var buf = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]);

//convert buffer to string
var str_buff = buf.toString();

//length of str_buff
var str_length = str_buff.length;

var numNewLines = 0; 

for (var i = 0; i < str_length; i ++)
{
    if(str_buff.charAt(i) == '\n')
    {
        numNewLines++;
    }
}

console.log(numNewLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you are trying to get the line length of current file.

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv):

> The first element will be 'node', the second element will be the name
>   of the JavaScript file.

So you should replace `process.argv[2]` with `process.argv[1]`.

Edit:

If you are passing a parameter for a file name on command-line like:

```
node server.py 'test.txt'
```

your code should work without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. You should check the file that you are using for the input.

Comment: my file is just a .txt file with contents: asdfadfasdfas\nasdfkjasdlfka\naskdfjldskfjasd\na;sdlkfjadsf (note the \n). and my second param is just "path/to/file"